# How to Switch Docusign Branding Dynamically through C# API for Powerforms

Tags: c#-4.0, docusignapi, powerform

Team,
I have many documents multiple companies on single docusign prod account.
I need to use multiple logo as per different-different company logo for powerforms.

I want to switch branding dynamically as per company, so that when my code detects a company, I must be able to set branding as per selected company ; so that whenever email is sent, company logo is sent with email.

I am using c# APIsc for docusign.
Your help is really appreciable in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can accomplish this with DocuSign, you just need to create the multiple brand profiles you want to use in your account, then specify which brand you want to use each time you create an envelope.

To specify which brand to use for a given envelope, there is a `brandId` property that's part of the envelopeDefinition that you can configure.  To get a list of valid brand GUIDs from your account you can make the [GET Brand Profile Information](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Brand%20Profile%20Information.htm) API call.